# In MPAndroidChart, How to make the lengths between the two labels on the x-axis and y-axis equal

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the MPAndroidChart library and have implemented a LineChart. I have set the maximum and minimum values for both the x-axis and y-axis, and the width and height in the layout are set to match_parent. The issue I am facing is that the lengths of the two labels on the x-axis and y-axis are not consistent.

[the lengths of the two labels on the x-axis and y-axis are different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgKLb.jpg)

The current requirement is to have the lengths of the two labels on the x-axis and y-axis consistent so that the grid appears as a square. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want the chart to appear as a square, you would generally control that in your XML layout rather than the chart itself.